# How to schedule a work in Azure Batch from Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-batch

everyone.

Is there any way to schedule a work on Azure Batch from Logic App? I would like to process a file by its insertion event in Blob Storage.

If you know other methodologies to do that, I will appreciate your help. :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow `:)` I am not a down voter but I can definitely see that this question is very open ended, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also try to co-relate how and at least provide links to various tools and scenarios in play here. Hope, this helps in better formatting this question so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you don't need Azure Batch and logic app doesn't support Azure Batch.

As for your requirement, you could just use [Blob connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) to implement. There is a trigger: [When a blob is added or modified (properties only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger), I suppose this is what you want, after the trigger you could add actions to process your blob file.